# How do i display the modal box after the input in the input column is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i display the modal box after the input in the input column is filled with a bar code scanner and filled input in modal by the bar code scanner from the input box before.

Comment: do you have a code, so we can see the issue?

Comment: i don't have the code, that task from my mentor. he give me and idea but i don't know how to do. the idea is how to show a modal box if input is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( function() {
  $("#barcode").click(function(){
      var value=$(this).attr("value");
      $( "#result" ).val(value);
    });
   $( "#result" ).focusout(function() {
  if( !$(this).val()) {
   alert("input is empty"); 
  } else{
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } 
   });
  });
```

```css
#dialog{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="barcode" value="ProductXXX">Barcode Scanner</button><br>
 <div id="dialog" title="Modal">
   <p>Congratulation! The input is not empty.</p>
 </div>
  <form id="basic">
  <input type="text" name="result" id="result" placeholder="Type something in">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

do you mean something like this? if you type in something and focus out it checks whether input was empty or not and gives you a message

Comment: <div id="dialog" title="Modal">
   <p>Congratulation! The input is not empty.</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type something in"></div> // the input must have a value from #barcode

Comment: <div id="dialog" title="Modal"> <p>Congratulation! The input is not empty.</p> <input type="text" id="result"></div> // the input **#result** must have a value from **#barcode**

Comment: ok I added a button with the id barcode and it copies its value into input result. hope this helps